# $2x^2 + xy + 2y^2 = 0$ a pair of straight lines

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

Is the following equation a Pair of Straight lines ?

$2x^2 + xy + 2y^2 = 0$

I can see $h^2 - ab$  is negative. I do not think it will be a Pair of Straight lines. Then what is it ?

Can anyone please explain ?

Comment: Look at a simpler example of the same type: $x^2+y^2=0$. Can you see what the graph of that equation is?

Comment: yes.$(0 , 0)$..@GerryMyerson

Comment: Good. Now can you see why your equation is of the same type?

Comment: Is it true that  the equation with $ \Delta = 0$  and $h^2 - ab < 0$  will represent a point ? @GerryMyerson

Comment: I bet you can work this out yourself, by completing the square.

Comment: Actually I was thinking for more general case. If I am given $ax^2+2hxy+by^2+2gx+2fy+c$ with $\Delta = 0$  and $h^2 - ab < 0$   then how can I show it will represent a point only.@GerryMyerson

Comment: I bet you can work this out yourself, by completing the square.

Comment: Making any progress, Sani?

Comment: I have got the answer. Thank you for your guidance.@GerryMyerson

Comment: Good. Let me encourage you to write up what you have, and to post it here as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using $|xy|\le \frac 12(x^2+y^2)\quad$  (from $(|x|-|y|)^2\ge 0$)

You get that $\, 2x^2+xy+2y^2\ge \frac 32(x^2+y^2)$ so this can be zero, only for $x=y=0$ and your locus is degenerated in the origin point only.

Answer (score 1):

$x^2+y^2+x\frac y2=0\implies x^2+2x(\frac y4)+(\frac y4)^2+15y^2/16=0\implies (x+y/4)^2+15 y^2/16=0$, which is possible on reals if and only if $(x,y)=(0,0)$ and hence the equation represents a point (degenerate conic).

Comment: Good, but I really wish you had guided OP to figure this out instead of doing it all yourself. I was trying to do this in the comments.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: noted.

Comment: Is it true that  the equation with $ \Delta = 0$  and $h^2 - ab < 0$  will represent a point ?

Comment: Why not try to mimic Koro's calculation, and work out the answer yourself, sani?

Comment: Actually I was thinking for more general case. If I am given $ax^2+2hxy+by^2+2gx+2fy+c$ with $\Delta = 0$  and $h^2 - ab < 0$   then how can I show it will represent a point only.@GerryMyerson

Comment: @sani: Yes that will represent a point. Hint for general case: write the general equation as quadratic in $x$ or $y$ and try to find out when you can factor that into two linear factors.

Answer (score 1):

The polynomial is homogeneous of the second order. You can factor it by rewriting

$$2\frac{x^2}{y^2}+\frac xy+2=0.$$

Then solving the quadratic,

$$\frac xy=\frac{-1\pm i\sqrt{15}}4,$$ gives the complex straight lines

$$4x+(1-i\sqrt{15})y=0$$ and $$4x+(1+i\sqrt{15})y=0.$$

Comment: So can we say it is a Pair of straight lines ?@Yves Daoust

Comment: On cartesian plane? No!

Comment: @sani: I said complex straight lines.

Comment: How can you guarantee that it will not be any other conic section ?@YvesDaoust

Comment: It will not represent straight lines even on Argand plane and the reason is even there points are denoted by $(x,y)$ with both x, y real and in Argand plane (x,y) represents $x+iy$.

Comment: @sani: what else ?

Comment: I do not know. I am not sure. Can you please elaborate little bit ? @YvesDaoust

Answer (score 1):

Plotting the graph of this function on desmos tells me that well its a...... **Point!**
[image]

In general to know whether it is a point check for $h^2 < ab$ and $ \Delta = 0$ where $\Delta = abc + 2fgh - af^2 - bg^2 - ch^2$

Pair of Straight Lines would satisfy $\Delta = 0$ and $h^2 = ab$

**EDIT**: In general theory the condition I wrote for a point is the condition for the conic to represent non real lines 
References: https://brilliant.org/wiki/conics-discriminant/